# Android Json And value(number) check if no then action

Tags: android, json, if-statement, key-value

i want  help in Json(http) with app version checker

example json file link is http://example.com/check.json
this file read
and j-son file response like below,

```
{
"version": "1",
"team": "App Version Check",
"data": "Send Value",
"about": [
    "http://example.com/apk.apk",
    "http://example.com/logo-app.jpg"
]
}
```

after check value string

version

if (version value is equal to install app version )

{no any action}

else

{action any some activity example}

read json and if value equal no action if value equal then some activity

Answer (score 0):

I can provide some of the answer

```
String jsonString = // the json string. from download or resources etc...
String appVersion = // current app version
try
{
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    String versionInJSON = jsonObj.optString("version", "PUT FALL BACK VERSION HERE, IF NOT FOUND");

    if(versionInJSON.equals(appVersion))
    {
        // versions are the same
    } 
    else
    {
        // version mismatch
    }

}
catch(JSONException ex)
    // TODO - could not parse JSON
    // make assumptions version same (?) it is up to you
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```